# Dock isn't responding to mouse movement in Yosemite when external mouse (Cyborg R.A.T. 5) is attached

Tags: macos, dock, mission-control

For the past few days now, I've come across a peculiar error with my Dock. It won't respond to my mouse moving down to the bottom of the screen until I click it, and when it does, it won't change the active icon when I drag my mouse over it. Here's [a video](https://youtu.be/bKkYcL4U9GE) of what happens.

This is accompanied by a peculiar error in Mission Control where I can't click on windows to enter them until I drag them a little bit. Here's a video of [that phenomenon](https://youtu.be/fVwCDrv44iY).

---

Update: I've found out that this happens when I attach my external mouse (a Cyborg R.A.T. 5) to the computer. I'll test other external mice and then maybe file a bug report with Apple.

Comment: Upon a further Google search, it looks like the Cyborg R.A.T. line in general has problems with Macbooks. I guess I won't be using it anymore.

Comment: I've added 'Cyborg R.A.T. 5' to your title, as your research may prove useful to future Googlers.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so it turns out the thing I was doing wrong was having an external mouse attached to the Macbook. As soon as I detached the mouse (an old Cyborg R.A.T. 5), everything started working normally again.

But it's still weird that that happens.